# Multiple rows are still being returned per user when pivoting on Course name

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I was hoping someone could help me.

In our database, we have a user table containing all of our users. Each user could have multiple training courses that they have completed. My task is to:

a.) Find the most recent completion date for each training course per user

b.) pivot on the training course so that we have one record per user, with a column for each training course, containing the most recent completion date.

The problem I am having is that it is still returning multiple rows per user and I can't understand why this is happening.

Here is the T-SQL Script I have:

```
SELECT userForeName,
       userSurname,
       CASE
           WHEN [Anti-Fraud] IS NULL
           THEN 'Course not started or incomplete'
           ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [Anti-Fraud], 121)
       END,
       CASE
           WHEN [Approved Assessors and UNIQUS] IS NULL
           THEN 'Course not started or incomplete'
           ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [Approved Assessors and UNIQUS], 121)
       END
FROM
(
    SELECT u.Forenames AS [userForeName],
           u.Surname AS [userSurname],
           m.Name AS [moduleName],
           tt.Name AS [courseName],
           ut.completed AS [lastCompleted]
    FROM radar.[User] u
         JOIN training.UserModule um ON u.Id = um.UserId
         JOIN training.Module m ON um.TrainingModuleId = m.Id
         JOIN training.TrainingTask tt ON um.TrainingModuleId = tt.ParentTrainingModuleId
         JOIN training.UserTask ut ON um.Id = ut.UserTrainingModuleId
) AS sourceTable PIVOT(MAX(lastCompleted) FOR courseName IN([Anti-Fraud],
                                                            [Approved Assessors and UNIQUS])) AS pivotTable;
```

Current output:

userForeName      userSurname                       Anti-Fraud  Approved Assessors and UNIQUS
Adam    Conneely  Course not started or incomplete  Course not started or incomplete
Adam    Conneely    Course not started or incomplete    Course not started or incomplete
Adam    Conneely    2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 Course not started or incomplete

Expected output:

userForeName    userSurname Anti-Fraud  Approved Assessors and UNIQUS
Adam    Conneely    2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 Course not started or incomplete

Comment: add your current output & required output.

Comment: I have done this although not in a good format (sorry I'm new to this and couldn't figure out the correct way of formatting the data as a table).

Comment: Column names - 'userForeName', 'userSurname', 'Anti-Fraud', 'Approved Assessors and UNIQUS'. The rest are the values for each column.